# How to make kaltura player?

Tags: media-player, kaltura

how to customize a player using kaltura player?
link is here https://github.com/kaltura/mwEmbed
please help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this really the right site for this question?

Comment: Tell me exactly, what customizing you need?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at below url, it states you how to manage the player.

http://knowledge.kaltura.com/faq/how-use-kaltura-player-studios-additional-parameters-and-plugins-uivars-flashvars